# Ceiling fan halogen light no longer controllable with remote, however the fan speeds remain controllable by the remote

Tags: ceiling-fan, light, remote-control

I installed the Hampton Bay ceiling fan with halogen light several years ago, where previously there was only a ceiling light fixture controlled by a single wall switch.

The new ceiling fan/light came with a remote control.   With the wall switch on I was able to control the fan speed and dim the light and turn the light completely off. It functioned perfectly for at least seven years.

This is no longer the case.  The fan speeds continue to function as they did with the remote but the halogen light turns on full brightness when I flip the wall switch but can no longer be dimmed or turned off with the remote.
Of course the light turns off by the wall switch also.

There are many occasions when the fan is operating that I do not want the light on or want the light dimmer.

I'm a handy guy but this has me baffled.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It sounds like the remote button has failed on the remote, or something has burned out inside the remote control module up in the fan cowling.

Comment: I 2nd harper; I have a remote one that came with the house where the light button was worn out. If I really mashed it and slid it while smooshed I could get it to work, cleaning the button pads didn't help. I ended up soldering up a new physical button, but getting a replacement remote would probably be simpler for most folks...